# Как задать ограничения страницы html

Tags: html, css

Хочу задать ограничения на ширину страницы html, что-бы если отображается очень длиная строка без пробелов, то внизу не появлялся ползунок, ибо это все портит. Например есть строка `<p>тутДолжноБытьОченьДлинноеСообщениеИзОднойСтрокиБезПробеловКотороеНеУмещаетсяВЭкран</p>`
И нужно что-бы она переносилась на следующую строку если не вмещается в экран. `max-width` не работает в данном случае, я пробовал. Просьба подробно объяснить решение, ибо я по большей части пишу бэкенд и не понимаю html.

Comment: `<p word-wrap: break-word;>тутДолжноБытьОченьДлинноеСообщениеИзОднойСтрокиБезПробеловКотороеНеУмещаетсяВЭкран</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в css существует свойство `word-break` (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/word-break). Оно как раз и управляет тем, где будет установлен перевод на новую строку в случае превышения текстом границ блока.

```css
p {
  max-width: 100px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>тутДолжноБытьОченьДлинноеСообщениеИзОднойСтрокиБезПробеловКотороеНеУмещаетсяВЭкран</p>
```